# angular router with optional params doesn't navigate

Tags: angular, parameters, angular2-routing, option-type, angular-routing

I am using angular 2.4 and I am trying to navigate from the route :

```
{route:'/heroes',HeroesComponent}
```

to the same route but with passing optional params via:

```
this.router.navigate(['/heroes',{name:foo}])
```

The problem is that only the URL changes and the router doesn't navigate.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?  Any JS or Angular error will break routing.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer nope. There are no errors.

Comment: I think it should be `this.router.navigate(['/heroes'],{name:foo});` -- right bracket moved.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer this does not even change the url and I believe the syntax is wrong. The params have to be inside the square brackets I think.